# What is the best framework to develop games for Android?

Tags: android, java, javascript

I have an Android 2.2 device and I want to try to develop games for it.

I have three questions:

1. What is the best frame work to develop games.
2. Are there any good JavaScript ports or frameworks that let me develop to JavaScript and then to compile to Java ? ( or something like that )
3. Where do I start to learn how to develop for the Android?

Comment: What does it have to do with JavaScript? Someone please retag this question, unless you plan to make HTML5 apps.

Comment: PhoneGap. Or web games

Comment: just asked if there is javascript wrapper in one of the game frameworks that all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various tools you can use to make games such as [marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmalade) or [unity3d](http://unity3d.com/) for android

However, the android UI system is the main barrier preventing you from just porting something across from java or c++ or whatever else. In any case, some stuff is just easier to do using the android framework rather than manually doing yourself in opengl-es or with your own drawing code (such as displaying and updating a text-string score)

Generally, I'd suggest having a play with making some simple apps that explore different UI elements of android, as well as following some of the tutorials on the [***ANDROID DEVELOPERS WEBSITE***](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html). Then look more closely into whether it is easier to port some game over, use one of the above mentioned tools or try and do everything yourself using the android framework and java/c/c++

Also, android 2.2 you can use opengl-es 2.0 if you decide on 3D games. Otherwise higher api level will only impact on the game if you are trying to do something really specialist that only comes with a later api level

Comment: unity3d also has the advantage of allowing you to program in javascript which you seem to want.